# How to prevent access to DVD and USB ports in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, optical-drive

How do I prevent access to the DVD drive and USB ports in Windows 7 unless an admin password is entered?

Also, if I could, I would like users to connect an Apple iPod *without* needing to enter a password (but not for any other device).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the DVD drive and physically destroy the USB ports. No, seriously. [If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore.](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx)

Comment: Also, it's impossible for Windows to tell whether the device is an iPod until it's too late.

Comment: While the answer is technically true, it doesn't really help the original poster.

There are several reasons for an admin to disable USB/DVD ports even though there's a possibility of someone exploiting them with a specially tailored hardware.

Comment: As I said it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write an utility for this. The utility should also be smart enough to connect with the iPod and verify if it's the iPod you intended, but I'm not sure if its a 100% possible because Windows 7 actually would have to be injected with a kind of "malicious" code that can alter the Windows 7 driver management.

This is my flowchart I'd use in code: The utility is active in any Windows 7 mode. Then it knows at any time if there are administrator rights. It blocks all access constantly, unless the necessary conditions are met.